# Select section except a div child

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've made a click event on the `section.artist-info`, but the problem is I won't have that click event on the `.core-info`. So I've write this CSS selector `.artist-info:not(.core-info)` for select the element I need and don't need. But it didn't work. So my question is now how can I select the `section.artist-info` except the child `div.core-info`? Here is my code:

```js
$("body").on("click", ".artist-info:not(.core-info)", function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("preview-lied")) {
        alert("clicked");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <section class="artist-info"> <!-- I'll select this -->
        <div class="toggle-panel"> <!-- I'll select this inclusieve the child -->
            <p>&#9776;</p>
        </div>
        <div class="core-info">  <!-- I won't select this inclusieve the child tags -->
            <h1 class="titel">artist</h1>
            <p class="bold">Top nummers</p>
            <ul class="top-nummers">
                <li>number 1</li>
                <li>number 2</li>
                <li>number 3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: div:not can help you do that, your usage of not is not like what it is explained at documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `>` to `.artist-info:not(.core-info)`

```js
$("body").on("click", ".artist-info:not(> .core-info)", function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("preview-lied")) {
        alert("clicked");
    }
});
```

```css
.artist-info {
 background: gray;
}

.core-info {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="artist-info">
        <div class="toggle-panel"><p>&#9776;</p></div>
        <p class="fa fa-pause fa-2x big-play"></p>
        <div class="core-info">
            <h1 class="titel"></h1>
            <p class="bold">Top nummers</p>
            <ul class="top-nummers">
                <li>number 1</li>
                <li>number 2</li>
                <li>number 3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: I think OP want to select parent not child on click, or i might be wrong.

Comment: No problem mate `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Read carefully about `:not`. Your code should be

```js
$("body").on("click", ".artist-info div:not(.core-info)", function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("preview-lied")) {
        alert("clicked");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <section class="artist-info">
        <div class="toggle-panel">
            <p>&#9776;</p>
        </div>
        <div class="core-info">
            <h1 class="titel">artist</h1>
            <p class="bold">Top nummers</p>
            <ul class="top-nummers">
                <li>number 1</li>
                <li>number 2</li>
                <li>number 3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

When you write `.artist-info:not(.core-info)` the browser trying to find section with class `.artist-info` without class `.core-info`. But when you add `.artist-info div:not(.core-info)` browser looking for `div` which is into `.artist-info` and with class `.core-info`